# jq insert new key in json and parameterized value

Tags: jq

I am trying to insert new key/value in json using jq.
I am able to successfully insert the key but my value comes from a variable but I am not able to set it properly.

Here is my Code:

```
SHORT_NAME=`jq -r '.properties.cluster_name' filepath` //Output is "abc-test-00"
//Insert new key into json 
jq '.properties += { "short_name": "$SHORT_NAME" }' filepath 
    // It inserts short_name under properties but it shows "short_name" = "SHORT_NAME" instead of actual value
    ("abc-test-00")
```

JSON:

```
{
  "properties":
  {
     "cluster_name": "abc-test-00",
     "short_name": "$SHORT_NAME" 
  }
}
```

What I am missing ?

Comment: Please note that there is no need to use shell variables.  With a very small modification to your program (e.g., using jq variables), you can achieve the result using just one invocation of jq.

Comment: @peak : Example ?